# How to solve the problem "bookmarks are not allowed" when submit a paper?

Tags: bookmarks

I need to upload a paper (pdf). But the system informed me that "bookmarks are not allowed". However, I have no idea how to forbid bookmarks in the Tex file. Should I add any command? Thank you in advance.

p.s., the packages I load are:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,cite,graphicx,delarray,subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{eps}{*}{}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
```

Comment: Bookmarks are not generated per se but usually by means of an additional package, like hyperref or so. Maybe you tell us what exact packages you load then one can probably see which ones cause the bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The packages I load are:


    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{psfrag}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,cite,graphicx,delarray,subfig}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{eps}{*}{}
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the `hyperref` manual, this code should remove the production of bookmarks in the pdf;

```
\hypersetup{bookmarks=false}
```

You have to write this line in the preamble of your document

Answer (score 0):

Tried various methods found online but none worked.
Finally I found this working solution: use pdftk to remove bookmarks in command line.

`pdftk A=example.pdf cat A1-end output nobookmarks.pdf`

In order to execute the command, you have to download the pdftk server version (which is actually the free command line interface of pdftk).